# Calculate the tendency of a set of samples

Tags: approximation, regression, correlation

I develop an application in which I constantly get samples of heart pulse.

I defined an interval of $t$ seconds.

In each $t$ seconds I have $n$ samples.

In every interval, I want to calculate the tendency of those $n$ samples. For example, lets say I have $n = 5$, and I have samples with values $\{70, 88, 95, 103, 115\}$. I want to recognize I have a growth in the heart pulse, and I want to have some measure for the rate of grows/decrease/almost no change.

I thought on two approaches for solving this problem.

1. I calculate the linear approximation for the $n$ samples using linear regression by applying least squares implemented by the normal equations. (I treat each sample as two coordinates vector with $x$ coordinate as time and $y$ coordinate as heart pulse). I get from the normal equations a linear function of the form $y = mx+b$ and my measure for the tendency is the slope, i.e. the $m$ value.
2. The second approach is to calculate the correlation (pearson's correlation) between vector $x$ and vector $y$ when $x$ is the time and $y$ is the heart pulse.

I'm asking which approach do you think is better for my problem (determining the tendency of heart pulses). Or, do you have a better algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: Can those voting to close please tell the OP how to improve their question.

Comment: The two approaches yield identical information and even share the same underlying calculations. But there are indeed (slightly) better algorithms, such as Poisson regression, and--depending on circumstances--much better algorithms indeed. By "circumstances" I mean the amount of data, how frequently you want to update your estimate of rate of change, and whether that needs to be done in real time or retrospectively. Perhaps you could share a little bit more of that context with us?